# Как адаптировать меню?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать что-бы меню равномерно уменьшалось при уменьшении экрана?

```css
#head {
  max-width: 1679px;
}

#top_menu {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 1679px;
  background: #384148;
  padding-left: 157px;
  padding-right: 350px;
}

#menu {
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
}

#menu ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 1276px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

#menu ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#menu ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FBF7F7;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  padding: 24px 45px;
  background: #414850;
  border-left: 1px solid #191b1d;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

#menu ul li:first-child a {
  border: 0px;
}

#menu ul li a:hover,
#menu ul li:hover a {
  background: #363c42;
}

#menu ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 67px;
  right: -12px;
  display: none;
  width: 208px;
}

#menu ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

#menu ul li ul li a {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-transform: none;
  padding: 17px 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid #656d78;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
}

#menu ul li ul li a:hover {
  background: #707883;
}
```

```html
<div id="head">
  <div id="top_menu">
    <nav id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Текст</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Текст2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Текст3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">текст4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">текст6</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Проверка</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Пример текста</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Надпись</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Текст</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">текст7</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: В полном размере]

Comment: надо что бы не уменьшалось а что бы складывалось , вы используете flexbox и в медиа запросе вместе flex-direction:row; поставьте flex-direction:column; уменьшите padding и т д

Comment: Думаю стоит установить ширины и высоты не в пикселях а в процентах или `vh`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body {
  margin: auto;
}

#top_menu {
  height: auto;
  background: #384148;
}

#menu {
  max-width: 1679px;
  margin: auto;
  height: auto;
}

#menu ul {
  display: flex;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

#menu ul li {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#menu ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FBF7F7;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  padding: 24px 1rem;
  background: #414850;
  border-left: 1px solid #191b1d;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

#menu ul li:first-child a {
  border: 0px;
}

#menu ul li a:hover,
#menu ul li:hover a {
  background: #363c42;
}

#menu ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 67px;
  right: -12px;
  display: none;
  width: 208px;
}

#menu ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

#menu ul li ul li a {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-transform: none;
  padding: 17px 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid #656d78;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
}

#menu ul li ul li a:hover {
  background: #707883;
}
```

```html
<div id="head">
  <div id="top_menu">
    <nav id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Текст</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Текст2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Текст3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">текст4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">текст6</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Проверка</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Пример текста</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Надпись</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Текст</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">текст7</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```